# Scrollable table with original data table working with slicers/filters

Tags: excel, vba

Original Table: Table1

Scrollable Table: Table2

I can make make the scrollable table (Table2) work using the index function and scroll bar just fine, but when I apply filters/slicers to Table1 the rows say 1,6,7,12 go away because of the filter/slicer being used and Table2 stops working because it is using the index function and many rows have disappeared.

I hope that is enough explanation of the problem. Is there a work around to this situation? Can we build scrollable tables without the index function? I've looked everywhere and can't find anything on this specific situation.

Comment: What is a scrollable table?  What is an example of the function you're using?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpgB8XHnGxY

That's an example of a scrollable table. Basically you have a table with say 100 rows, but you want a table in your dashboard that's 10 rows with the ability to scroll through the whole 100 rows. I can do that, my problem comes when applying filters and slicers to the original 100 rows table which is the "data source?" for the scrollable table.

Comment: I don't really enjoy watching videos but there's a downloadable example here: https://www.annielytics.com/blog/excel-tips/create-scrolling-table-excel-video/ which for anyone who's interested is pretty easy to figure out....

Comment: Example here https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XCuWbj81o-cJO5OHKXuRnEgLyoB3f88/view?usp=sharing  It's a bit complicated to explain in detail but basically it uses SUBTOTAL() to detect filtered rows and some array formulas (using SMALL and INDIRECT) to link the appropriate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example using `SUBTOTAL()` (which can detect if it's in a hidden row)

[image]

Downloadable example:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XCuWbj81o-cJO5OHKXuRnEgLyoB3f88/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you SO much for the example file ! You already got it to work and that's exactly what I need to do so I'll just continue to figure out the example to use it myself. 
I'll do some research to learn how to use this functions in other applications.
You're awesome !